# Return HTTP error code or 2xx with empty content

Tags: json, http, rest

I'm a little new to the REST world and I'm not sure on the expected functionality of certain REST APIs.

I have a REST API that takes an ID and some JSON and my function will tack on more values to the JSON and return it

My problem arises when a there is no record for the given ID. Would it be better practice to return an HTTP error code indicating that ID was not found or should I return a 2XX code with empty JSON in the content?

Comment: I'm tempted to ask: how exactly is that a REST API in the first place? Is this a POST request?

Comment: Yes it is a POST and my JSON is the content of the POST

Comment: a) Is this is a retrieval operation, the method should be GET. b) a 404 would be correct if the URI maps to no currently available resource -- but if you hide the addressing inside the request body...